# Software to debug Safari-specific website issues as a PC user

Tags: windows, osx, safari

Suppose a modern web application where OSX users report an issue that occurs only in Safari, but not in Chrome or other browsers. Suppose also you work primarily on a PC with Windows. What software would you recommend to debug this problem?

Must have:

- Run exactly the current Safari browser version for Mac OSX. (The issue is very likely to be specific to that combination, I'm afraid that emulation or ancient versions will not exhibit the problem.)

  *Note that a different WebKit browser (e.g. Chrome) is not sufficient. I'm really after the current combi of Safari on OSX. (In this particular instance because that combi does not accept cookies on CORS requests unless the user had visited the domain before.)*
- Developer tools / JavaScript debugging tools.
- Not having to buy a Mac.

Would like to have:

- I prefer not having to buy an OSX license, i.e. I prefer a gratis solution.

Nice to have:

- Persistent setup. (That is, this is explicitly not a "Must Have", i.e. if needed I'm "okay" with a VM that self destructs after e.g. two weeks. But it would be *nice* if the solution is persistent.)
- Ability to test different / older versions of Safari.

In the past I had used "Safari for Windows", but AFAIK that is no longer being updated.

Comment: Would be the use of the same engine as Safari help? The engine of Safari is WebKit. No Google Chrome has forked the WebKit engine and put there own spin to it. So it's not the same engine anymore.

Comment: No, absolutely not: a different WebKit will not do. I'll clarify that in the first must-have.

Answer (score 2):

I think [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com) is a great solution to this problem.

> Instant access to all real mobile and desktop browsers. Say goodbye to
>   your lab of devices and virtual machines.

However, it is not gratis. But if you are a web developer and need to test a lot then it is a great solution.